# Flask Jinja macro <input caller="Macro Anonymous">

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am new to using Jinja and am trying out macros in my flask app. So I have one macro that is calling another using the special call block like so:

```
{% macro macro1(x, y) %}                    
    <div class="row">
        {% call macro2(x,y)%}{% endcall %}
    </div>                    
{% endmacro %}
```

But when I view the rendered template I can see a strange caller attribute in my input field:

```
<input caller="<Macro anonymous>">
```

Have I done something wrong, I just wanted to know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the macro you are calling is not defined.

You defined `macro1` but you are calling `macro2`.

```
{% macro macro1(x, y) %}                    
    <div class="row">
        {% call macro1(x,y)%}{% endcall %}
    </div>                    
{% endmacro %}
```

There is a great example in the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#call) as well.

Comment: Hi Mekicha, thanks for the link. I just wanted to ask, I have defined both of my macros in the same file, so shouldn't macro2 be defined as well?

Comment: Yeah sure you can define that. But if you are calling, you have to call a predefined macro already

Comment: I noticed that in my file when I defined both macros and the second macro was calling the first, I still have the same issue. But this shouldn't occur right because I am calling a predefined macro, which is the one above it?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Maybe you can show the code you are talking about?

Comment: Okay I will update the code in my question. Also Mekicha, I noticed that if I remove the call block and just use this {{ macro1(x,y) }} then this solves my issue, but I have no idea why.